# Default batch size in aggregate command in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From [`aggregate` command doucumentation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/command/aggregate/):

> To indicate a cursor with the default batch size, specify cursor: {}.

However, I haven't found the value of such defaul or how to find it (maybe using a mongo admin command).

How to find such value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-batches):

> The MongoDB server returns the query results in batches. The amount of data in the batch will not exceed the maximum BSON document size.
>
> New in version 3.4: Operations of type `find()`, `aggregate()`, `listIndexes`, and `listCollections` return a maximum of 16 megabytes per batch. `batchSize()` can enforce a smaller limit, but not a larger one.
>
> `find()` and `aggregate()` operations have an initial batch size of 101 documents by default. Subsequent getMore operations issued against the resulting cursor have no default batch size, so they are limited only by the 16 megabyte message size.

So, the default for the first batch is 101 *documents*, the batch size for subsequent `getMore()` calls is undetermined but cannot exceed 16 megabytes.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not entirely wrong, I think it's 101 for aggregation pipeline.

See [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/a892a728ed8261d2af658b68d3aa06c697bee787/src/mongo/db/pipeline/aggregation_request_helper.h#L60)

Comment: this is a broken url

Comment: indeed, fixed it! It's still 101