# Mongodb Native Driver "find" errors if there are more than 100 documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have a collection of 200 documents, when I'm using the "find" method I've got an error

```
MongoServerError: Cannot run getMore on cursor 5866951209337451201, which was created in session bcd516cd-227f-4df6-bc52-5aca331c08e9 - 47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=, without an lsid
```

But if I limit the number of returned documents to 100 it works fine.

Comment: how do you create this command?

Comment: @dododo seems like MongoDB doesn't allow you to get more than 100 documents using the same cursor by default, to change this, I need to change batchSize option

Comment: batchSize is always there, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057720/default-batch-size-in-aggregate-command-in-mongodb. But it doesn't explain your error

Comment: @dododo As I understand if I need to map through the collection, I need to implement this by myself, like pagination?

Comment: you should use a default driver find cursor interface and configure skip: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/ and batchSize https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/#mongodb-method-cursor.batchSize options

Comment: @dododo I've found why it fails. It happened inside of the cron job, cause I forgot to establish a connection with the database 